# Imposssible to expand a database in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, troubleshooting

I am experiecing a strange problem. I have a SQL Server 20008 R2 instance that recently (after years of running smoothly) started to become slow.

One symptom that I notice is that when working from SQL Server Management Studio, on the server itself and logged as *sa*, I click on the + symbol near the database icon, after clicking I get an error and after OK I see that the  "+" is disappeared, you can see in this screenshot how it looks like after I tried on four databases:

[image: database tree]

The error I get is (in Italian):

```
Impossibile accedere al database MyDatabase. (ObjectExplorer)
------------------------------
Percorso programma:

   in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.DatabaseNavigableItem.get_CanGetChildren()
   in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItem.RequestChildren(IGetChildrenRequest request)
   in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ExplorerHierarchyNode.BuildChildren(WaitHandle quitEvent)
```

It means "Impossible to access the database MyDatabase".

This is just a symptom as I said, the main issue is that from a client the connection is slow, very slow but working.

I restarted the SQL Service service for this specific instance.

This is a named instance, I have also the default instance that works fine.

Can anyone give me a pointer to a solution please?

Comment: Is the `sa` SQL Server Login still in the `sysadmin` group? It could be a permission issue.

Comment: @hot2use, yes it is "public" and "sysadmin", by the way i experience the same problem also loggin in with any another administrator user.

Comment: After clicking the plus icon, do you get the error *immediately* (implying access or permission issues) or after some time (implying blocking or resource contention)?

Comment: I did a quick test and created a new database with an administrator account. After that I logged on to the server with an ordinary user and try to expand the new database. I get the same message as you get ("The database test is not accessible. (ObjectExplorer)") with the same callstack (at ....get_CanGetChildren() at ...RequestChildren(...) at ....BuildChildren(...)" (SSMS 12.0.5207.0 and SS 12.0.5207.0 EE). So at least I can confirm that missing rights can be one cause for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason was my pc had an issue in resolving DNS, each query to `SERVER\INSTANCE` was going in  timeout, using IP, Port solves the issue.

I did not find yet why the DNS does not work, but that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Open a new query window and run `SELECT * FROM sys.databases`.  See if the database in question is listed in the results.

If it is, see if you can access it by running `USE MyDatabase`.  If that works, see if you can pull up a list of tables by running `SELECT * FROM sys.tables`.

You may want to run `DBCC CHECKDB MyDatabase` and see if any problems are detected.